# XmlSerializer exception when deserializing derived class (<Derived xmlns=''> was not expected)

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize and deserialize a hierarchy of classes using XmlSerializer. The serialization works fine, but when I try to deserialize I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: `<Derived xmlns=''>` was not expected.

This is the xml that I am trying to deserialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Derived xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <BaseStr>Base</BaseStr>
  <DerivedStr>Derived</DerivedStr>
</Derived>
```

This is the code that I am using:

```csharp
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlInclude(typeof(Derived))]
public abstract class Base 
{
    public string BaseStr { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public string DerivedStr { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Derived));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.Serialize(ms, new Derived() { DerivedStr = "Derived", BaseStr = "Base" });

            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(ms.ToArray()));

            ms.Position = 0;

            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Base));
            Base b = (Base)deserializer.Deserialize(ms);
            Console.WriteLine(b.GetType().Name);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Why does the deserialization not work? How can I get it to work?

Comment: Thank you very much for including a short but complete example demonstrating the problem - if you could include using directives next time so we can just copy/paste/compile, that would be much appreciated. I've added them in here now.

Comment: Fix this line : XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Base));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating an `XmlSerializer` which *expects* to deserialize just `Base` objects. It doesn't expect to see a `<Derived>` element. If you use

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Derived));
```

you don't get the exception. Alternatively, when you *serialize* the instance of `Derived`, you can use a serializer which will produce a `<Base>` element:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Base));
```

That will still deserialize to an instance of `Derived`, because the XML will include

```
xsi:type="Derived"
```

Basically your serializer and deserializer need to be constructed with the same type.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. In my case, I have more than one derived class and I don't know which one I'm deserializing at runtime, so I will serialize them using `typeof(Base)` so that the serializer will write the `xsi:type` attribute. I have a follow-up question though: the next step for me is to implement `IXmlSerializable` to control the output. If I implement that interface, the `xsi:type` attribute is not written out, so the deserialization fails because the type is not known. Do you know what I can do about that?

Comment: @Ove: No, I don't know much about that side of things. I suggest you research for a bit longer, then ask a new question with an example.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I posted a follow-up question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/32370014/80003](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32370014/80003)